# OpenGL fragment shader not writing to fbo color buffer

Tags: opengl, glsl, fbo

I'm having trouble writing from my fragment shader to a color buffer in the FBO. The idea is to draw to this texture, and then draw this texture into a quad.
The thing is, the shader works when drawing to the default window buffer, since if I remove the FBO, the scene is displayed. And the texturing of the quad works too, I tried it with an imported texture, and it showed. All I'm getting is a black screen. What could have gone wrong? :(

Code for creating the FBO:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthbuff); //Add a depth renderbuffer for depth testing
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuff);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuff);

//Add the buffer to be drawn to and the buffer for the picking information
glGenTextures(1, &drawbuff);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawbuff);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawbuff, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &pickingbuff);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pickingbuff);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, pickingbuff, 0);
```

Code for rendering:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
GLenum buffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
glDrawBuffers(2, buffers);

shader->bind(); //If the three lines above are removed, it draws correctly to the window
drawStuff();
```

Code for the quad:

```
quadshader->bind();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
int drawTexID = quadshader->uniformLocation("drawTex");

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
//glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, anotherTexture); //This works. A texture imported from a TGA
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawbuff);
glUniform1i(drawTexID, 0);

drawQuad();
```

And lastly, the frag shader, I just set it to draw everything to a solid color:

```
void main(void) {
    gl_FragData[0] = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragData[1] = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

EDIT: If it is of any help, the whole thing is in a Qt GLWidget.

Comment: I'm seeing a distinct lack of framebuffer clearing code.

Comment: What do you mean? And by the way, the FBO returns complete.

Comment: Calls to `glClear` or `glClearBuffer`. Clearing the framebuffer before using it. Where are you doing that?

Comment: At the start of the drawStuff function, I have glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); I dont have any `glClearBuffer`, what does it do?

Comment: It turns out Nicol was right: Although I did clear the buffer for writing to the textures, i forgot to clear the default buffer just before drawing from the texture, and that's why it didn't refresh. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you careful to make sure that you're texture is not simultaneously bound to a sampler (glBindTexture), and a framebuffer? I believe the behavior is either an error or undefined if you try to write to a texture while it's bound to an active sampler, or if you try to sample a texture while it's attached to an active framebuffer.

Comment: I bind the textures to the FBO with `glBindTexture` at initialization, like in the first codebox above. How do I unbind them? 
At the end of the init, the framebuffer is unbound, then bound again for rendering, like in the second codebox, and the FBO is unbound at the end. Then the texture is bound again, for the rendering to the quad. Do you think that causes the problem?

Comment: glBindTexture doesn't bind a texture to an FBO, it binds it to a sampler. If you're not actively sampling the texture during a pass, it should be removed from the sampler via `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);` or by binding a different texture. The key step here is making sure that neither of your framebuffer-bound textures are attached to samplers while you're writing to the framebuffers.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried that, I added `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);` just after binding the framebuffer for rendering (and before the rendering calls), and I'm still getting a black square.

Comment: @rabipelais Hmm sorry not sure then. You may want to download gdebugger if you don't have it, it can view FBOs in memory and you can see if anything is actually being drawn to it.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of that, I will try and post here any news :)

Comment: THANK YOU! According to the debugger the textures are indeed being written to. (At least the FBO has two texture images that look suspiciously similar to what they should be.) So now I have to find why it isn't passed to the other shader. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: So yeah, I figured it out, the only thing missing was `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawbuff);`, isn't that great...
Now the texture is displayed, but it doesn't redraw the scene when I make the objects rotate (for example). But hey, nevertheless, one step closer :P thanks to all

Comment: Nice, now gDEbugger is giving me a segfault at startup :D (startup from the debugger, not the program)

Comment: I think I have the same problem. I'm trying to do something similar: want to render a fragment shader in a low resz via fbo, but I'm only getting a black screen. Have you solved this?